# Why postgresql@11 service failed instantly after i installed with brew on macos?

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew, apple-m1, postgresql-11

I've encountered problem about brew services on postgresql@11 right now. After i reinstalled ([from this blog](https://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2021-01-28-how-to-completely-uninstall-homebrew-postgres/)) postgresql@11 it instantly gives an error on `brew services`. Then i ran this  `brew services restart -vvv postgresql@11` it returns this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@11</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/.homebrew/opt/postgresql@11/bin/postgres</string>
        <string>-D</string>
        <string>~/.homebrew/var/postgresql@11</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>~/.homebrew/var/log/postgresql@11.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>~/.homebrew/var/log/postgresql@11.log</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>~/.homebrew</string>
   </dict>
   </plist>
```

When i check the `~/.homebrew/var/log/postgresql@11.log` file, it is empty. Also i check permissions on that file but it is ok(r,w). Still getting this error without any explanation(empty logs). 2 days ago it was working but somehow i broke it. Also i checked postmaster.pid but the file is not exist on my machine, i searched like this: `find . -name "postmaster.pid"`

Additionally, after i reinstalled postgresql@11 in my postgresql@11 directory (`~/.homebrew/var/postgresql@11`) is all empty.

Lastly, in my directory -> `~/.homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.13/bin` there is postmaster file but it is not postmaster.pid file i dont know what is it for, but when i do `ls -al` it shows like this -> `postmaster -> postgres`

My machine is macOS Big Sur 11.5.2 on m1 chip macos. Hopefully someone gives me an idea about it.

What i realize right now is i have problem with installation as well.
`brew postinstall postgresql@11` as a result ->

```
Last 15 lines from ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/postgresql@11/post_install.01.initdb:
2021-08-23 08:27:42 +0300

~/.homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.13/bin/initdb
--locale=C
-E
UTF-8
~.homebrew/var/postgresql@11

no data was returned by command ""~/.homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.13/bin/postgres" -V"
The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was not found in the
same directory as "~/.homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.13/bin/initdb".
Check your installation.
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall postgresql@11
```

However what i see is initdb and postgres in the same bin folder :/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew on M1 should be installed into `/opt/homebrew`. But from your output, `~/.homebrew` but not `/opt/homebrew` is used as `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX`. What happened to your installation?

Homebrew doesn't support to be installed into arbitrary directory. Don't export `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX` to change it.

---

Quote from [Homebrew FAQ](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-should-i-install-homebrew-in-the-default-location)

> Why should I install Homebrew in the default location?
>
> Homebrew’s pre-built binary packages (known as bottles) of many packages **can only be used if you install in the default installation prefix**, otherwise they have to be built from source. Building from source takes a long time, is prone to fail, and is not supported. Do yourself a favour and install to the default prefix so that you can use our pre-built binary packages. The default prefix is /usr/local for macOS on Intel, /opt/homebrew for macOS on Apple Silicon/ARM, and /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew for Linux. Pick another prefix at your peril!

Comment: This is because i export the path like that. The reason is, it will be more accesible. The below you can see my .zshrc file however i think this is not the case. @simba
```js
function path {
  if [[ -d "$1" ]] ; then
    if [[ -z "$PATH" ]] ; then
      export PATH=$1
    else
      export PATH=$PATH:$1
    fi
  fi
export PATH=''
path ~/.homebrew/sbin
path ~/.homebrew/bin
path /usr/local/sbin
path /usr/local/bin
path /usr/sbin
path /usr/bin
path /sbin
path /bin
```

Comment: Also it works on other executables but in here it dies immediately.
`postgres --version`-> output is -> `[1]    46094 killed     postgres --version`
`export HOMEBREW_PREFIX=~/.homebrew/` @Simba

Comment: @CanerTaşan What's the output when you start postgresql manually, with `~/.homebrew/opt/postgresql@11/bin/postgres -D ~/.homebrew/var/postgresql@11`?

Comment: It's same
`~/.homebrew/opt/postgresql@11/bin/postgres -D ~/.homebrew/var/postgresql@11
[1]    47327 killed     ~/.homebrew/opt/postgresql@11/bin/postgres -D ~/.homebrew/var/postgresql@11` @simba

Comment: Actually i reliase right now redis is running in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist` however postgres try to run in here `~/.homebrew/opt/postgresql@11/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@11.plist` @simba